# Trouble using example code for EY-80 gyro/accelerometer/barometer

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, sensors

I am trying to use the example code to read measurements from my [EY-80 All in one 9-Axis Motion Sensor (Gyro + Acceler + Magneto + Baro)](http://www.electrodragon.com/?product=all-in-one-9-axis-motion-sensor-gyroscope-accelerometer-magnetometer-barometer)

The [example code](https://github.com/Edragon/Arduino_sketch/tree/master/EY-80) is from their github repo.

I am getting the error(s) stated below shown  http:// i . stack . imgur . com/CAtf0.png (sorry for the odd link, I don't have 10rep yet to be able to post more than two links..)

I have done nothing but copy and paste in the example code.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After talking to a friend, I found out what I did wrong.

1. I needed to include all of the #include libraries.
2. I downloaded one of the libraries in html, instead of raw .h format which was messing up the program, so I downloaded the correct version.

The program is now working, and collecting data well!

If you find your readings to be off, change the update delay from 500ms to 20ms and the readings will drastically improve.